# R Send Email on Windows without Java

Tags: r, email

I have a script that sends an email with a pdf attachment using R and mailR. However, the windows server I am putting the script on does not have Java installed so mailR will not work. What are my alternatives? The mail server requires a username and password so I think sendmailR is out since it does not support authentication. It would be nice to do this from within the R script.

Comment: not without java but if your issue is authentication you should try the `mailR` package which does support it

Answer (score -1):

Honestly your best bet is probably to have a server with mail enabled and write a script that can execute on an HTTP call.

```
response <- download.file("http://{URL}/", "response.html", method="internal")
```